# Why are the guides printed?

Tags: adobe-indesign, guides

I am printing my document from Adobe InDesign CS 5.5 and it is printing the guides around the pages.

It has never done this before, and I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out how to stop these guides from printing.  I must have accidentally turned something on to make these guides print.

Comment: Does the PDF show these type of marks when you view the PDF on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

Printing or not printing the guides is an on/off feature of the `Print` panel. Make sure to uncheck that.

You've probably turned this on by accident, or using a preset which does that.

[image]

Comment: The option for "Print Visible Guides" is also an option when exporting to a PDF as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the checkboxes in the options section (print dialogue) is activated by mistake?
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_KEWvt1mbkkI/Sn7_uKRGXaI/AAAAAAAAAM8/-5idR6jEtPY/s320/a.jpg
("Options" under "Pages")